# Setting units of measurement in Meshlab

Tags: meshlab

If I import a text file into meshlab for control, how does it recognise the units of measurement? When using the 'Reference scene' tool my errors seem high, but again what units are these in?
Thnak you,
Jim

Answer (score 2):

MeshLab currently does not explicitly use any unit of measurements.
The numbers shown in the interface are the one read in the file. So if in your 3d file all the coordinates are expressed in meters then all the numbers shown in MeshLab will be in meters.

The main reason for this behaviour is that most of the 3D file formats do not say what is their units of measurement. So better say nothing than something that could be wrong.